# Trying to select a hidden field in a parent DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take the data-value from the image and put it on the hidden fields without using the hidden field's id.
Edit: I can't use the id's because the set repeats with a different Id.

```
   <div class="optionImageSelection">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnIn"> 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="iamge1.jpg" data-value="val1" class="optionImageSelect">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="image2.png" data-value="val2" class="optionImageSelect">
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
        <div class="optionImageSelection">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnIn2"> 
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="iamge3.jpg" data-value="val3" class="optionImageSelect">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image4.png" data-value="val4" class="optionImageSelect">
    </li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
function OptionImage(image) {
   this.selectImage = function () {

       //this works but it needs to be generic. 
       var hdnSelector =  $("#hdnIn");     
       //this doesn't work but it's what I need
       //var hdnSelector = $(image).parents('input:hidden:first');
       $(hdnSelector).val($(image).attr("data-value"));
        alert($(hdnSelector).val());

   };
```

}

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".optionImageSelect").click(function () {
       var oi = new OptionImage($(this));
       oi.selectImage();
   });
```

});

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4pMg/1/

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're using `data-` attributes, why not just add a `data-id` attribute to the images that targets the hidden field? `$($(image).attr("data-id")).val($(image).attr("data-value"));`

Comment: I can't use the id's because the set repeats with a different Id. I updated the sample to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Crazy train, that approach would work and be more independent of the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var hdnSelector =  $("#hdnIn");
```

you can use this selector

```
var hdnSelector =  $(image).closest('ul').prev('input')
```

You can use a combination of `closest` and `prev`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/p4pMg/4/)**

Comment: @vts.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('input[type=hidden]')` selector.

Comment: This will not work if there are multiple hidden fields on the page

Comment: @Sushanth-- Ohh... The condition has changed. Your method is very good.